# Displaying price on frontend based on different attribute

Tags: price, ce-1.9.0.1

Check the screen shot.
[image: mulcurr]

The attribute id for `price[USD]` is `75` and is stored in the table `catalog_product_entity_decimal`. The attribute ids of `Price[INR]` and `Price[EUR]` are `134` and `135` respectively and both are stored in the table `catalog_product_entity_varchar`. I want the value for Price[INR] to be displayed in product view page when a corresponding currency is selected from drop down list in magento header. I don't want magento to convert the values based on webserviceex rates. So I'm writing a module to achieve this.
Here is my code.

```
app/code/local/price/changer/etc/config.xml  

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <price_changer>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </price_changer>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <price_changer before="Mage_Adminhtml">price_changer</price_changer>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <global>
        <models>
            <price_changer>
                <class>price_changer_Model</class>
            </price_changer>
        </models>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_select_after>
                <observer>
                    <price_changer>
                        <class>price_changer/observer</class>
                        <method>priceUpdate</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </price_changer>
                </observer>
            </catalog_product_select_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

And observer.php in `Model` folder is like this:

```
<?php
class price_changer_Model_Observer {
    public function priceUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $product=$observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $price=$observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        if (value_id=2) {
            $price=$observer->getInfo()->getProduct();  
        }
        foreach ($price as $ => $value) {
            # code...
        }
    }
}
```

Observer.php is incomplete. How can I connect those 2 tables in DB to observer.php, so that it can be achieved?
P.S: I'm going to put some bounties for this question very soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it might just be easier to overwrite the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class, method `getFinalPrice`.

Haven't tested the code below but this should basically work since the **final price** is calculated from the **price**. However, if you fill in a special price it will get overwritten again. So no 100% foolproof code but hopefully a good jumping off point.

`app/code/[codepool]/[Namespace]/[Module]/etc/config.xml`

```
[...]
<global>
    <models>
        <price_changer>
            <class>price_changer_Model</class>
        </price_changer>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Catalog_Product</product>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </models>
</global>
[...]
```

`app/code/[codepool]/[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/Catalog/Product.php`

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Catalog_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
{
   public function getFinalPrice($qty=null)
   {
      switch(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())
      {
         case 'INR': $this->setData('price', $this->getData('Price[INR] attribute code')); breadk;
         case 'EUR': $this->setData('price', $this->getData('Price[EUR] attribute code')); breadk;
      }

      return parent::getFinalPrice($qty);
   }
}
```

Comment: So this observer.php isn't of much use, is it? Want to confirm before changing it.

Comment: Got this error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'getFinalPrice' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE).